# Is there a way to get solr to return a pdf with the query matches highlighted?

Tags: java, pdf, solr, solrj

I'm using solrJ to search pdfs that I have indexed in solr and stored in mongoDB.

Everything is indexed properly, and I'm able to get an html response with the query matches highlighted as expected, but the formatting is odd and there are a lot of garbage characters as a result of the conversion from pdf to text.

Is there a way I can get solr to just give me the pdf with highlights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way you can make Solr return a PDF with the PDF changed to highlight the matching parts.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. Do you happen to know of a way to do it that doesn't require any non-free (for enterprise use) libraries?

Comment: My guess is that you'll have to do that yourself by extracting and indexing each word and its associated coordinates in the document as a payload or metadata in some way, then add highlighting boxes with a PDF library.